# Select similar (i.e. not same) colours in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selections

I made a sketch on a piece of paper, photographed it and [used the *Image Trace* tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/image-trace.html). Now I have a vector image with a lot of detail.

[image: traced photograph]

I'd like to clean it up by removing those white and gray-ish chunks, and keep the dark strokes. [Most of the advice I'm finding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5cKrmCU74so) covers the *Select* → *Same* → *Fill color*, which selects only identical colours, and therefore doesn't really do it for me.

Do you think there's a way to automatically select all colours darker/lighter than a given threshold?